# Loop the included array

Tags: typescript, loops

currently im building a filter and in this filter there is an array with dynamic values.

Im just one step away from finishing it but i dont get the right loop done. I already tried it with something like forEach but all the ways i tried it didnt work. Here is the code:

```html
map(p => (!this.personTypeFilter) ? p:p.filter(((i:any) => this.getPersonTypesBezeichnung(i.personentyp)?.toLowerCase().includes(this.personTypeFilter.forEach((x:any) => { return console.log(this.personTypeFilter[x])))))
```

This way makes my code to explode
So the filter need to include all values step by step with a for loop or something like that

//EDIT

The goal of this situation is to filter a whole array for Example you have multiple checkboxes which will be pushed to an list after clicking the single checkboxes. Now i want to filter every single value of this list, so i thought about looping it with forEach. The correction solution instead was map.

Comment: Can you share the  exact error message you are getting? For starters, you are missing a closing curly bracket after `return console.log(this.personTypeFilter[x])`

Comment: got it by myself. Posting the solution now below :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of a complex for loop or forEach you can just use a simple map.
Just handle it similiar to a for loop, the map will go for all your elements in your array like below.

```html
map(p => (!this.personTypeFilter.map((x:any) => x)) ? p:p.filter(((i:any) => this.getPersonTypesBezeichnung(i.personentyp).includes(this.personTypeFilter.map((x:any) => x).join(', '))))),
```

Comment: A code dump with no explanation of how it relates to the problem in the question is unlikely to be of use to future readers

Comment: Idk what needs to be explained right there. Wrote a little bit more, hope it helps like that. Im not the best in things like that, im sorry.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you clarified the question more in line with [ask], that would help

Comment: Okay i hope i clarified it much more now and everyone knows what the goal was.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).